# Bad substitution from SLURM array

Tags: arrays, bash, slurm

The following batch script is meant to run a function against an array of files:

```
#SBATCH --job-name="my_job"
#SBATCH --partition=long
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --mem=30G
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=4
#SBATCH --time=3-00:00:00
#SBATCH --export=ALL
#SBATCH --output=array_%A_%a.out  
#SBATCH --error=array_%A_%a.err

FILE=${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}
base=$( basename $1 .fasta)
echo ${FILE}
OUTFILE=~/data/${base}.afa

mnj -in ${${SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID}}  \
-out $OUTFILE
```

It returns the following error:

```
/var/lib/slurm-llnl/slurmd/job512763/slurm_script: line 12:

: bad substitution
```

From the command line, `NUMFILES=${#FILES[@]}` returns the appropriate number of files and `echo $FILES` returns the expected output.

I can't find any SLURM array examples that run through a directory of files without `FILE=${FILES[$SLURM_ARRAY_TASK_ID]}`. I'm not sure why this is causing an error other than maybe a bash version/syntax difference?

```
echo "${BASH_VERSION}"
4.3.48(1)-release
```

Answer (score 0):

Your script does not have a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) so it is interpreted using the default shell, which can often be `sh` or `dash`, which do not understand that syntax.

Try adding `#! /usr/bin/env bash` as the first line of your submission script.